# How should I handle Django Rest Framework Unique Field Hyperlinked relationships?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to write a custom update for DRF HyperlinkRelatedModel Serializer. But really I'm just banging my head against a wall.

It throws up unique constraint errors. First I wanted to have a unique constraint on the email, that wasn't working so I removed it. Now I get the same error on the `uuid` field.

Can someone please walk me through this, and offer some advice on handling these sorts of relationships.

Below is what I have so far, it's meant to create or update a `Recipient` and add it to the `Email`.

I believe I need to write some form of custom validation, I'm not sure how to go about that. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
{
    "recipients": [
        {
            "uuid": [
                "recipient with this uuid already exists."
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Update**

This removes the validation error. Now I don't know how to add the validation back in for regular updates.

```
extra_kwargs = {
    'uuid': {
        'validators': [],
    }
}
```

*Models*

```
class Recipient(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email_address = models.EmailField()

class Email(models.Model):
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    body = models.TextField()
    recipients = models.ManyToManyField(Recipient, related_name='email')
```

*Serializers*

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.exceptions import ValidationError

from schedule_email.models import Recipient, Email, ScheduledMail


class RecipientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipient
        fields = ('url', 'uuid', 'name', 'email_address', 'recipient_type')
        # I saw somewhere that this might remove the validation.
        extra_kwargs = {
            'uuid': {
                'validators': [],
            }
        }


class EmailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    recipients = RecipientSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ('url', 'uuid', 'subject', 'body', 'recipients', 'delivery_service')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        recipient_data = validated_data.pop('recipients')
        email = Email.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for recipient in recipient_data:
            email.recipients.add(Recipient.objects.create(**recipient))

        return email

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        recipients_data = validated_data.pop('recipients')
        for field, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, field, value)

        for recipient_data in recipients_data:
            if 'uuid' in recipient_data.keys() and  instance.recipients.get(pk=recipient_data['uuid']):
                Recipient.objects.update(**recipient_data)
            elif 'uuid' in recipient_data.keys() and Recipient.objects.get(pk=recipient_data['uuid']):
                instance.recipients.add(Recipient.objects.update(**recipient_data))
            elif 'uuid' in recipient_data.keys():
                raise ValidationError('No recipient with this UUID was found: %s' % recipient_data['uuid'])
            else:
                recipient = Recipient.objects.create(**recipient_data)
                instance.recipients.add(recipient)

        return instance
```

Below is an example of a post/put request I might make. I probably don't need the `uuid` field I couldn't workout how to get the `Recipient` instance from the hyperlink url.

*Example Post/Put*

```
{
    "subject": "Greeting",
    "body": "Hello All",
    "recipients": [
      {
        "url": "http://localhost:8000/api/recipient/53614a41-7155-4d8b-adb1-66ccec60bc87/",
        "uuid": "53614a41-7155-4d8b-adb1-66ccec60bc87"
        "name": "Jane",
        "email_address": "jane@example.com",
      },
      {
        "name": "John",
        "email_address": "john@example.com",
      }
    ],
}
```

Comment: How are you sending requests to create and update Email instances? And are you getting the above mentioned error while creating or updating Emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your relation structure, while creating an **Email** instance, you also pass data for **Recipient** instances, either new recipients or existing recipients. The validation error you mentioned happens because when you use nested serializers, while creating or updating, DRF calls nested serializer's **is_valid** method, and when you pass a Recipient data for an existing recipient, DRF tries to validate this as if creating a new Recipient with the data you provided (including **uuid**), and raises a validation error. To overcome this, in your **EmailSerializer**, you can disable default validation for **recipients** field, and add a custom validator method for it, and run the validation like this:

```
class EmailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ...
    def validate_recipients(self, value):
        for recipient_data in value:
            if recipient_data.get('uuid'):
                try:
                    recipient = Recipient.objects.get(uuid=recipient_data.get('uuid'))
                except Recipient.DoesNotExist:
                    # raise a validation error here
                else:
                    serializer = RecipientSerializer(recipient)
                    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # This will run validation for Recipient update
            else:
                    serializer = RecipientSerializer(data=recipient_data)
                    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True) # This will run validation for Recipient create

        return value
```

The above code first checks if uuid provided for a Recipient, if so, expects it to be the data for an existing Recipient, if not, expects it to be the data for a new recipient, and runs the validations accordingly. Then, in your create method of EmailSerializer, you can create / update the recipients through its serializer like this:

```
for recipient in recipient_data:
    if recipient.get('uuid'):
        serializer = RecipientSerializer(Recipient.objects.get(uuid=recipient.get(
            'uuid')))  # We know this wont raise an exception because we checked for this in validation
    else:
        serializer = RecipientSerializer(data=recipient)
    serializer.is_valid()  # Need to call this before save, even though we know the the data is valid at this point
    serializer.save()  # This will either update an existing recipient or createa new one
    email.recipients.add(serializer.instance)
```

The approach in update method of the EmailSerilaizer should be similar, but you also take into account cases where a recipient is removed from the list of recipients of an email.

Note: do not raise ValidationError inside create / update methods of serializers, run the validations in validate methods, and use create / update methods only for creating / updating. Write those methods with this mindset: If I made it through to this method, the provided data must be valid, so I will just go on with creating / updating the instance. And write your validations keeping this in mind, too.

*Example Serializers*

```
class RecipientSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipient
        fields = ('url', 'uuid', 'name', 'email_address', 'recipient_type')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'uuid': {
                'validators': [],
            }
        }


class EmailSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    recipients = RecipientSerializer(many=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Email
        fields = ('url', 'uuid', 'subject', 'body', 'recipients', 'delivery_service')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        recipient_data = validated_data.pop('recipients')
        email = Email.objects.create(**validated_data)
        self.add_recipients(email, recipient_data)

        return email

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        recipient_data = validated_data.pop('recipients')
        for field, value in validated_data.items():
            setattr(instance, field, value)

        self.add_recipients(instance, recipient_data)

        return instance

    def validate_recipients(self, recipients_data):
        validated_data = []
        for recipient_data in recipients_data:
            if recipient_data.get('uuid'):
                try:
                    recipient = Recipient.objects.get(uuid=recipient_data.get('uuid'))
                except Recipient.DoesNotExist:
                    raise ValidationError('No recipient with this UUID was found: %s' % recipient_data.get('uuid'))
                serializer = RecipientSerializer(recipient, data=recipient_data)
            else:
                serializer = RecipientSerializer(data=recipient_data)

            serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
            validated_data.append(serializer.validated_data)

        return validated_data

    def add_recipients(self, email, recipients_data):
        for recipient_data in recipients_data:
            if recipient_data.get('uuid'):
                serializer = RecipientSerializer(
                    Recipient.objects.get(uuid=recipient_data.get('uuid')),
                    data=recipient_data
                )
            else:
                serializer = RecipientSerializer(data=recipient_data)
            serializer.is_valid()
            serializer.save()
            email.recipients.add(serializer.instance)
```

Comment: This is the clearest solution I've read for this, thank you so much. Now going through and updating my code.

Comment: @Sarcoma haven't tested this code, though used similar approaches in past projects. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: I've added my updated code, I'm now getting a `You cannot call `.save()` on a serializer with invalid data.` error when updating a `Recipient`.

Comment: Fixed that one I was using the wrong variable inside a list. Still checking through but looks to be on the right track.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it was really helpful. I've added the code that I have working now. Feel free to improve anything that seems out of place. I still needed to remove the validation on the recipient, I guess I need to add that back in manually somehow, do you have any ideas how that might work?

Comment: @Sarcoma you mean uuid validation on RecipientSerializer? Still get the same error if you add that?

Comment: if I don't the `extra_kwargs` bit on the RecipientSerializer that disables the unique check I still get the `recipient with this uuid already exists.` error.